# I'M not able to build my unity project into android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I tried almost everything but was still not able to solve this error.
Here are the errors I get

**Error 1**

```
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "F:\Game deveopment\Battle Strike\36347040-commando-survival-strike-shooting-gameunity-3d-action-source-code\Main Files\NewCommandoAndSurvival\NewCommandoAndSurvival\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.RuntimeInitializeOnLoadManagerInitializerModule.dll"
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.GetFileStream (System.String fileName, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) (at <ebb9e4250ed24cbfa42055e3532ef311>:0)
Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) (at <ebb9e4250ed24cbfa42055e3532ef311>:0)
Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) (at <ebb9e4250ed24cbfa42055e3532ef311>:0)
UnityEditor.AssemblyReferenceChecker.CollectReferences (System.String path, System.Boolean collectMethods, System.Single progressValue, System.Boolean ignoreSystemDlls) (at <ef3b6bf002d8435a97b4e938f6c49b02>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.PrepareManagedResources.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <caed2e60415e48d1850197a030a83f5f>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <caed2e60415e48d1850197a030a83f5f>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <caed2e60415e48d1850197a030a83f5f>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <caed2e60415e48d1850197a030a83f5f>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <ef3b6bf002d8435a97b4e938f6c49b02>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

**Error 2**

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 368 seconds (368233 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

**Error 3**

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ca] in <ef3b6bf002d8435a97b4e938f6c49b02>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <ef3b6bf002d8435a97b4e938f6c49b02>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Comment: Get rid of the spaces and dashes and other weir characters in your folder names

Comment: If that doesn’t work it may also be worth trying with a shorter (combined) file path to your project folder

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.